# Does STAB affect energy gained?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know that same-type-attack-bonus (STAB) increases the *damage* of same type moves, but does it increase the *amount of energy gained*(to fill up the charge bar) when using quick moves of the same type?

Some websites seem to suggest so (rankedboost etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this site](http://pokemongoden.com/2016/08/29/advanced-pokemon-go-gym-mechanics-guide/#), when either attacking *or* training a gym,

> Energy gained per hit points loss -2 HP = +1 energy

Due to the fact that there is a Same-Type Attack Bonus mechanic in the game that increases damage, one can infer that the higher damage dealt by STAB moves leads to higher energy gains.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Eikre's explanation in the comments, my previous answer actually applies to bonus energy being gained from *taking* extra damage due to the STAB bonus.

Therefore, there does *not* seem to be a bonus in energy gain for inflicting more damage with STAB moves. In addition, you can see exactly how much energy you would gain for any given attack [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vcobt/posthotfix_pokemon_go_full_moveset_rankings/d5xxrfg?st=irwag3hm&sh=18860cb0).

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain something I missed?

Comment: Pokemon gain energy from losing their *own* HP, not from inflicting HP damage. Though your answer is, in a way, technically correct, it's also misleading.

Comment: @Eikre Oh, seriously? Do you have a reference? I'll update my answer if that's true.

Comment: It's an implication observed in *your* reference, if you would care to read it. It is also more explicitly described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wqk0j/i_did_some_testing_and_can_confirm_defending/).

Comment: Ah okay, I misread my own reference then. I guess this answer needs an overhaul so allow me to fix it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Eikre the answer has been updated, thanks for your help

Comment: I switched my vote, but the reference at Serebii you posted is [out of date](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vcobt/posthotfix_pokemon_go_full_moveset_rankings/d5xxrfg?st=irwag3hm&sh=18860cb0).

Comment: @Eikre updated (again)