# In Pokemon Go, is it better to have small defects for Attack, Defense, Stamina, or one big defect and perfect in other areas?

Tags: pokemon-go

For example, if a Pokemon can have  Attack, Defense, Stamina of

```
14  14  14
```

Is that better than

```
15  15  12
```

Their perfection scores are the same: 93%, but one is more well rounded and one is perfect in two areas but with a bigger defect in one area.

Similarly, would that be better if it is

```
13  13  13
```

as opposed to:

```
15  15  09
```

or

```
14  14  11
```

?

Comment: Depends what you want for your Pokemon. Do you want a well-rounded Pokemon or one that is more offensive like Vaporeon, defensive, or has tons of health like Chansey?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing- as for your examples, I would think that generally 14,14,14 would be better than 15,15,12 but not by enough for it to really matter. It probably would depend on the pokemon and their attacks. I personally would take the 15,15,12, but not a 12,15,15 or a 15,12,15. I would think that attack and defense are more important than stamina.  Usually. As for your other example, I would probably take 14,14,11 but I would consider it just as good as 13,13,13. The 15,15,09 however, I would NOT accept.

Comment: The comment section is not intended for extended discussion, answering the question, debating the merits of that comment answer, or insulting each other. If you wish to continue this discussion, and are able to do so in a civil manner (aka be nice), then feel free to make a chat room and move the conversation there. Do not continue your discussion any further here.

Answer (score 5):

## Given the same sum of individual values, the most powerful distribution is the one that compensates for a Pokémon's weakest base stats.

Let me begin by introducing two premises:

**Every Pokémon species is characterized by base statistics.** For example, Pidgeys have a base attack of 94, base defense of 90, and base stamina of 80. Any *particular* Pokémon's stats are the three sums of its individual value plus its species' base stat, so the actual stats of a Pidgey with IVs of 10-10-10 would be 104, 100, and 90.

**Attack, Defense, and Stamina have almost* strictly proportional importance.** Regardless of the numeral value of a particular stat, doubling it will make you twice as effective and halving it will make you half as effective. Defeating your opponent twice as quickly, taking half the damage from their attacks, or being able to take twice the damage on the nose all result in the same capacity to fight and win against an opponent who is 200% as strong as otherwise.

* (I say "almost" because stamina actually has a [knock-on effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/284796/161656) that results in more energy for charge attacks. Also, while defense and HP will enable you *to win* a more difficult fight, attack will help you finish it *faster,* and I assume your time has value.)

Observe that though the first premise describes an additive relationship, the second describes a multiplicative one. The magnitude of these values is all relative. What you want are not the biggest numerical additions, but the *greatest percent increases.*

By way of example: Chansey is a Pokémon with extremely unbalanced base stats; she has only 40 base attack and 60 defense, but a phenomenal 500 base stamina. Getting an attack IV of 15 would constitute a 37.5% gain in actual power over the having an attack IV of 0, but a stamina IV of 15 would only be a 3% gain over the base. Literally, just *two points* of attack IV will eclipse the worth of a maxed out stamina IV. Same goes for defense. Yes, that means a 10-0-0 Chansey rated at only 22% "perfection" will outshine a 0-5-15 specimen rated 44% "perfect."

## HP and Defense are more important for Pokémon you intend to train at friendly gyms.

In this, there are, again, two premises:

**More Prestige is awarded for using a Pokémon with less CP.** Ideally, you want your Pokémon to have *half* the CP of the defender [for the greatest prestige gains.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/276189/161656) You're assisted in this endevour by dodging, exploiting type weaknesses, deliberately placing a defender who sucks, and by understanding that...

**The CP formula overvalues attack quadratically, compared to stamina and defense, and, um... cube-root-zenzically, compared to the level coeffecient.** The CP formula question is `(ATK*sqrt(DEF*STM)*CPm^2)/10`, but a better approximation of a Pokemon's power would be `ATK*DEF*STM*CPm^3`, where *CPm* is the level coefficient.

I dunno why Niantic based CP on such a skewed approximation, but you can exploit it by favoring stamina and defense and minimizing attack, which will result in the greatest (favorable) disparity between your CP and your actual combat viability. Yes, this means a 0-15-15 Pokémon, rated only 66% "perfection," is actually the ideal candidate for raising prestige.

## Among your Magnificent Six, Attack has the greatest utility.

When you attack an enemy gym, you get to bring six entire Pokémon and there is literally no single defender who can stand up to that kind of heat. With enough potions and time, you and your boys can raze absolutely any enemy gym, period.

Since merely *winning* is assured, the strategy is in minimizing the resources you're burning, which, as stated, are potions and time. To to this, you need to shorten the fights, which you can achieve by emphasizing offensive power.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thanks for your work and obviously very mathematical understanding!

Comment: +1 for `cube-root-zenzically`. I'm unashamed to admit I giggled.

Comment: Where did the formula `ATK*DEF*STM*CPm^3` come from, or where does it apply?  In searching the internet, I have never seen it before.

Comment: Among several good points, in the first part of the answer, the second premise is correct only if the factors (Stamina, Attack, Defense) are equally weighted.  However, the CP formula favors Attack, which explains why Chansey works as an example.  Similar reasoning fails on Pokemon whose highest base stat is Attack.

Comment: @Jerry These notions are both accounted for. Are you criticising the *structure* of the answer?

Comment: Hm, I cannot tell you how many times I have read over your answer, but I think I understand now the second premise.  I had assumed you were referring to the CP formula, but I think you are referring to the damage formula, which is not clearly referenced.  Perhaps some clarifying edits would help people understand your comprehensive answer and attract more up-votes.

Comment: The CP formula is indeed referenced. That would be `(ATK*sqrt(DEF*STM)*CPm^2)/10`, like I said. It does not depict a Pokemon's actual battle-fitness; as per the first premise, each stat has proportional value to the other. The formula `ATK*DEF*STM*CPm^3` is, thus, a better approximation of a Pokemon's real power. The second premise is built around the fact that these are very different formulas. The damage formula is at no point referenced.

Comment: OK, this time you misunderstand me.  I see three parts in your answer.  Part 2 refers to the CP formula, and it is fine.  Part 1 has two premises which thoroughly confused me; this was my previous comment.  You also have a formula to approximate a Pokemon's power, which I have never seen before but am interested to know its origin.  Overall, your answer has lots of interesting info and would benefit from some citations.

Answer (score -2):

While the comments are accurate and answer the question, the differences are irrelevant in instances where their bonuses are very similar. Move sets & pokemon level make a bigger difference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked. I've caught *hundreds* of Eevees. I'm also a high enough level where powering up a few select Vaporeons isn't a big deal for me. If I have 2 Vaporeons with the same move set that I like but with only slightly different IVs, which one is better? The one with some max IV's and some that are lower, or the one that has IV's that are more well-rounded but not maxed out? The information in your answer is no help in deciding that.

Comment: In that case, the attacker would win. It just really doesn't matter enough.